# How to fetch distinct count from a MongoDB collection using Java code?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

This is my MongoDB query:

```
db.getCollection('xyz').distinct("uid",{p_id:"abc",action:"mno",time_lo_res:{$gt:new ISODate("2020-06-22T04:00:00")*1 , $lt:new ISODate("2020-06-23T04:00:00")*1} }).length
```

How can I fetch this count in a Java console application

Comment: You can use the Java driver's [Collection#distinct](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html) method.

Comment: Bson abcQuery= new BasicDBObject("p_id","abc")
        .append("action","mno")
           .append("time_lo_res", new Document("$gt",epochTimeStart).append("$lt",epochTimeEnd));
     String u_id;
      long abccount= database.getCollection("xyz").distinct(u_id, abcQuery).count;

Comment: Getting this error - The method distinct(String, Class<TResult>) in the type MongoCollection<Document> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Bson)

Comment: I think you need to use this version of the method: `distinct​(String fieldName, Bson filter, Class<TResult> resultClass)`. You can try using the `Document.class` for the `resultClass`.